# Sending a different welcome message every time

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

The code is to send a different welcome message every time a new member logs on to the server (DM message).

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', ReBeL => {
  var bel = ["Welcome 1 @", "Welcome 2  @!", "Welcome 3 @"]
  var moon = bel[Math.floor(Math.random() * bel.length)];
  moon = moon.replace('@', ReBeL.user)
  setTimeout(function() {
    member.createDM().then(function(channel) {
      return channel.send(moon)
    }).catch(console.error)
  }, 4000)
});
```

This is the error:

```
member.createDM().then(function (channel) {
^

ReferenceError: member is not defined
at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/cabox/workspace/bot.js:10:4)
at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

Comment: what mistakes? what error?

Comment: would be more readable in the question - but since `bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {` isn't even part of the code you posted in the question, then there is no help

Comment: `client.on('guildMemberAdd', ReBeL => {` your code .... vs the code with error `bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {` - how do you explain that?

Comment: Sorry I made the mistake I was trying to fix the code, I added the error to the question

Comment: well, member is not defined anywhere in the code you posted, so, there's your problem

Comment: I try to fix it but I do not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way and it works. I tested it.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
var ReBeL = member.user.username;
var bel = ["Welcome 1 @","Welcome 2  @!","Welcome 3 @"]
var moon = bel[Math.floor(Math.random() * bel.length)];
moon = moon.replace('@', ReBeL)
setTimeout(function() {
member.createDM().then(function (channel) {
return channel.send(moon) 
 }).catch(console.error)
 },4000)});
```

You can add servers and member count too. You need to do it this way:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
var ReBeL = member.user.username;
var ReBeLserver = member.guild.name;
var ReBelcount = member.guild.memberCount;
var bel = [
    "Welcome @, we hope you will enjoy staying in @server ",
    "Welcome @ you are #th member! We hope you will enjoy staying in @server"
]
var moon = bel[Math.floor(Math.random() * bel.length)];
moon = moon.replace('@', ReBeL)
moon = moon.replace('@server', ReBeLserver)
moon = moon.replace('#', ReBelcount)
setTimeout(function() {
member.createDM().then(function (channel) {
return channel.send(moon) 
 }).catch(console.error)
 },4000)});
```

Here's an example with embeds, I added discriminator too.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
var user = member.user.username;
var server = member.guild.name;
var count = member.guild.memberCount;
var discriminator = member.user.discriminator;
var bel = [
    "Welcome @#$, we hope you will enjoy staying in @server ",
    "Welcome @#$ you are -th member! We hope you will enjoy staying in @server"
]
var welcome = bel[Math.floor(Math.random() * bel.length)];
welcome = welcome.replace('@', user)
welcome = welcome.replace('@server', server)
welcome = welcome.replace('-', count)
welcome = welcome.replace('$', discriminator)
setTimeout(function() {
member.createDM().then(function (channel) {
    let welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(`RANDOM`)
    .setDescription(welcome)
return channel.send(welcomeembed) 
 }).catch(console.error)
 },100)});
```

Comment: Works beautifully Thank you, it seems you have experience. I have a question about how to prevent bot from sending a message to a specific person's ID